# Python package to create "webseed" torrent file?

Tags: python, bittorrent

The [bittorrent extension called webseed](http://bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0019.html) allows a simple HTTP/FTP server to help serve content to a BitTorrent network. I'm serving content from a HTTP webserver, and I'd also like to provide .torrent files to seed using this method. I'd like to use Python to generate the .torrent files.

Which Python torrent library could/should I use to facilitate webseeding?

[The PyPi index lists lots of python bittorrent packages](https://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3aaction=search&term=torrent&submit=search), but I'm hoping that I don't need full torrent client functionality, just something that can create these .torrent files with all the checksums etc. I don't mind using a full-featured lib, just not sure what to go for in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it seems at least that [libtorrent can put webseed info into the torrent file](http://libtorrent.org/reference-Create_Torrents.html), and this can be used via the `python-libtorrent` package. (This means it's not a pure-python approach but that's OK.)

Code sketch:

```
import libtorrent as lt
piece_size = 256 * 1024
creator_str = "python-libtorrent"
thetracker = "your desired tracker"
theurlseed = "your desired url seed"

fs = lt.file_storage()
lt.add_files(fs, "/tmp/torrentme")
fs.num_files()

t = lt.create_torrent(fs, piece_size)
t.add_tracker(thetracker)
lt.set_piece_hashes(t, ".")

t.set_creator(creator_str)
t.add_url_seed(theurlseed)
t.generate()
```